# How to put method within a function

Tags: node.js

I'm a beginner in programming, how can I pass a method inside a function?

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    getUsers() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Create a class.  Import the function. & use it

Comment: Do u mean pass parameters or arguments inside a function e.g `function(num)` or a callback inside a function e.g `function(num, function (){})`

Answer (score 0):

Just create functions.. thats so simple as below:

```
class Users{

function getusers(){
}

function users(){
getUsers();
}

}

exports.Users = Users;
```